# CSMA/CA and wi-fi repeaters

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, repeater, 802.11

I found this interesting article: Why Don't Wi-Fi Repeaters Work Very Well - OK, Why Do They Suck? [1](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/988492-why-don-t-wi-fi-repeaters-work-very-well-ok-why-do-they-suck)

The author has good points. After a few posts the author says something that catches my attention:

> 'However - when the repeater is talking to one of its own clients, then the root AP can take that opportunity to talk to one of its own clients too. So now you have both the root AP and the repeater talking to a separate client at the same time...on the same channel - and there is no coordination going on between the repeater and the root AP...they will both transmit/receive with their client as they see fit. That's like two sets of conversations going on between two groups of people at the same time in close proximity (i.e. overlapping)....and the conversation for one group is just noise for the other group and vice-versa.....thats your interference.'

Isn't what standard CSMA/CA all about ? To avoid this type of situations ?

Comment: You can't avoid it on a single radio - that's why mesh uses a wired or separate radio for the backhaul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't what standard CSMA/CA all about ? To avoid this type of situations ?

I'm going to wildly guess that a repeater introduces a case of the *[hidden node problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem).*

CSMA/CA only works between nodes that can hear (and avoid) each other's transmissions. But usually you have a repeater precisely *because* the client cannot hear the AP or vice versa – which therefore means they cannot coordinate with each other anymore.

The repeater, however, still hears both transmissions – and since they can occur at once, it might not understand them.